# Checking and update data in a table on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table **A**, a view **v_B** and a daily job schedule **s_A**.

Through **s_A** I inserted value of **v_B** into a temp table **@A**, truncate **A** and then inserted into **A** with value of **@A**.

The problem was **v_B** increased records day by day and now it's over `50,000` records and it took too much time for the job.

Is there way to increase the performance? or just only update and insert the difference of the **v_B**, not truncate and reinsert all. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is incomplete and messy so can you please add some detail with proper breakdown. And yes, obviously you will get the solution.

Comment: Truncate and reinsert is fast operation. Problem is in poor v_B view performance. Optimize it.

Also, you can share view code for better success

Answer (score 0):

**It depends...**

For example when you have to update huge number of rows then `truncate and insert` will be a better choice.

on the other hand when you have very less number of rows to be updated then `update and inserting the remaining rows` should do well.